# Map a normal distribution N(x,s) to an ordinal response variable

Tags: normal-distribution, ordinal-data, psychometrics, latent-variable

I am working on a simulation. I am going to extract a series of normally distributed values from a distribution $N(x,s)$ whose mean $x$ and variance $s$ is known. I want to pretend that such distribution $N(x,s)$ is a latent causal variable that determinates a response ordinal variable $O$ which is in a known range (i.e. $[1,10]$). All other characteristics of $O$ (value distribution) are to be determined on the basis of $N$. What function could I use to map $N$ values to $O$? Since this is just a demonstrative simulation of an algorithm working on ordinal data (this mapping is not the core of the simulation, but it is part of the generative data process) and I am not oriented toward any particular psychometric theory, I am looking for some advice for a simple mapping function, though it would be better if based on some psychometric theory.

Comment: Besides (presumably) being piecewise monotonic increasing, what properties do you want the result ($O$), or the function relating the two to have?